# R: Transform 2 columns into a data frame based on counting column values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to reshape 2 columns of a data frame into a 
new data frame. Both columns have text values. I need to count
each combination of values and put them in a data frame.

Below is an example of 2 columns I need to use:

2 Columns from data frame:

```
   Col1 Col2
    A   Z
    B   Z
    B   Z
    C   X
    C   Z
    D   X
```

Desired output will show the count of each combination:

```
    Z   X
A   1   0
B   2   0
C   1   1
D   0   1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table` on the dataset

```
table(df1)
#       Col2
#Col1 X Z
#   A 0 1
#   B 0 2
#   C 1 1
#   D 1 0
```

If we need the output as a 'data.frame'

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df1))
```

Comment: You are correct. I had tried it on my data frame. Your good works great. Thank you for the help.